# How to avoid url decoding of $location.url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**My angular $location**

I have an encoded URL such as `var slug = 'test-test/7%2F8-test';`. I am using `$location.url(slug)` to redirect but unfortunately it gets decoded when it comes to the browser.

The same encoded URL should seen in the browser.

The current behavior in the browser is: `www.test.com/test-test/7/8-test`
Expected behavior is: `www.test.com/test-test/7%2F8-test`

But when I use path it gets encoded again.

Any help please?

I guess `$location.ur()` is decoding it by default. Any help on how to overcome this problem?

[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L388](http://location.js)

My another concern is while entering the direct encoded URL on the browser its get decoded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use vanilla javascript?

```
document.location = "http://www.google.com/test%fdsfsd";
```

will maintain the `'%'` sign..

Comment: Am using angular js single page app.

Comment: Is there any workaround in angularjs itself to solve this problem.