# Extend encodeURIComponent such as to skip some values from encoding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a URL such as .

```
var url = `damen/hosen-roecke/7%2F8-laenge`
```

While encoding
 `encodeURIComponent(url)` it returns `damen%2Fhosen-roecke%2F7%252F8-laenge`

But I need to skip this particular part `7%2F8` from encoding which is already encoded once.
So I guess how to override `encodeURIComponent` so that it can skip this particular format `'7%2F8'`

So that it can work like after encoding it should return `damen%2Fhosen-roecke%2F7%2F8-laenge`

Comment: Explain please _Problem is : using AngularJS should not exclude using vanilla js._

Comment: @Tushar Am getting a url slug from an api Its in a format which is already encoded. but when i use angulars $location.url(url) its get deocded automatically when it comes to the browser. Again when i use $location.path(url) its get encoded again. The strange thing is when i pass a pure url without any encoding there is no change while it comes to the browser. So I thought of to use $location.path() with the already encoded url and to overright the encodeURIcomponent such as to skip '7%2F8'.

Answer (score 2):

As the string contain some part that is encoded, first decode the string and then encode again.

```
encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(url)) // "damen%2Fhosen-roecke%2F7%2F8-laenge"
```

```js
var url = `damen/hosen-roecke/7%2F8-laenge`;
document.body.innerHTML = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(url));
```

**Steps:**

1. `decodeURIComponent(url)` will give completely decoded string `"damen/hosen-roecke/7/8-laenge"`
2. `encodeURIComponent("damen/hosen-roecke/7/8-laenge")` will give the `"damen%2Fhosen-roecke%2F7%2F8-laenge"` string.

Comment: Yes that good. but my main problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100002/how-to-avoid-url-decoding-of-location-url/36100119?noredirect=1#comment59843667_36100119